# MS Access 2003 with ODBC connection to SQL Server 2008, can only insert one row at a time

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc

Insert one row successfully, but with a ODBC call failed error. Then it keeps on failing with

> failed to insert new row in the recordset due to system error

for row 2 ... to n.  But can write many rows to a local Access table successfully. Write to SQL , 1 row only.

Answer (score 0):

After recreating a table on SQL with schema as close to Access' as possible, this problem has been resolved. Not exactly sure what made the differences, but issue resolved.